# easy for loop not working

Tags: java, for-loop, while-loop, do-while

So I was trying to make 
(EX) Enter some values: 1 -2 -3 2 5 
num of positive num is 5 num of neg num is -3 
total is 3 avg is .6 
I wanted to make it like this but when i run it, 
it doesn't work 
what part is error???

```
import java.util.*;


public class Welcome {

public static void main(String [] args){

    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
System.out.print("Enter an int value, the program exits if the input is 0: ");
    int num = input.nextInt();
    int countpos = 0;
    int countneg = 0;
    int totalnum = 0;
    int total = 0;
    double avg = 0.0;

    while(num != 0){

        if(num < 0)
            countpos++;
        else
            countneg++;

        total = total + num;
        totalnum++;
    }

    System.out.print("num of pos is: " + countpos);
    System.out.print("num of neg is: " + countneg);
    System.out.print("total is: " + total);
    System.out.print("the avg is: " + total / totalnum );

}
```

}

Comment: "Doesn't work" is not an adequate problem description. Which part(s) produce the undesired output? What is expected? What is the actual? Was there a compiler error? Exception? Does it run forever? Eat ice cream?

Comment: not related, but I think you want to switch the sign on your ``if``inside the loop. It seems like you're counting the positive numbers when they're actually negative.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you have to do `num = input.nextInt();` in the loop too

```
 while(num != 0){

        if(num < 0)
            countpos++;
        else
            countneg++;

        total = total + num;
        totalnum++;

        num = input.nextInt();
    }
```

Comment: ok, i over simplified a little. just copy that line in the loop

Comment: what about num in while loop it isn't declared since it is in while loop